# With templates: Operator resolved first or conversion resolved first?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I saw some interesting compiler behavior yesterday and I think I understand why it's happening, but I want to be sure.  So, I'm not going to write my reasoning, just the facts.

**Note, it's not a typo that I've included `vector` instead of `string`**.  I did it intentionally so that the compiler would not be able to understand what an std::string was and so that it would have to search around to figure out which operator I'm referring to by `+`:

```
#include <vector>
// #include <string> // intentionally commented out

template <typename T> struct A
{
    A() { };
    ~A() { };

    int m_member;
};

template <typename T> A<T> operator+(double lhs, const A<T> &rhs);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string fullString = std::string("Hi ") + std::string("mom!");
}
```

So, I get a slew of compiler errors in MS Visual Studio 2005.  I'm only showing a subset of them.

```
1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2784: 'A<T> operator +(double,const A<T> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const A<T> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        .\test.cpp(16) : see declaration of 'operator +'
```

... errors continued ...

```
1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2784: 'std::_Vb_iterator<_MycontTy> std::operator +(_Vb_iterator<_MycontTy>::difference_type,std::_Vb_iterator<_MycontTy>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vb_iterator<_MycontTy>' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\vector(1800) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
```

... errors continued ...

```
1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2784: 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<_MycontTy> std::operator +(_Vb_const_iterator<_MycontTy>::difference_type,std::_Vb_const_iterator<_MycontTy>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vb_const_iterator<_MycontTy>' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\vector(1695) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
```

... errors continued ...

```
1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2784: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::operator +(_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\vector(396) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
```

... errors continued ...

```
1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2784: 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc> std::operator +(_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>::difference_type,std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char,
1>            _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>            _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>        ]
1>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\vector(264) : see declaration of 'std::operator +'
```

So, the compiler searches around for the what the `+` means and complains that it can't deduce the appropriate template arguments.  I'm surprised by two related things, **one** is that it gives this error for each overloaded `+` operator that involves templates.  This tells me that the compiler has absolutely no way of ruling out that any of these `+` are not meaningful; **two**, which is related, that it doesn't just complain that no suitable operator exists.

I see this as an opportunity to learn something about how templates are instantiated and compiled.  Does anyone have any good explanation or references?

Comment: Oh, and just a comment on why the compiler even knows about `std::basic_string<...>`. It's included from `<vector>` via `<xfunctional>` via `<xstring>`. :)

Comment: +1 That's interesting. I wondered that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, since it couldn't find a match it's using the errors to tell you the *possible* operator candidates it actually found.

The g++ error for example tells you that it can't find the operator and then provides the same slew of messages, but in "candidates are:" form rather than one error per operator.

It's doing this in an attempt to be helpful: Since it couldn't find a match it assumes you may have actually meant *any* of the possible available operators.

Comment: Several people answered, but this came first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note, it's not a typo that I've included `vector` instead of `string`**.  I did it intentionally so that the compiler would not be able to understand what an std::string was and so that it would have to search around to figure out which operator I'm referring to by `+`.

This is not correct.  The compiler *does* know what `std::string` is.  Consider, for example, that the following program compiles just fine (using Visual C++ 2010, but it should also work in 2005):

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string s;
}
```

When using Visual C++ (at least Visual C++ 2005 through 2010; I can't speak for other versions), including `<vector>` also includes whatever internal header declares and defines `std::basic_string` and `std::string`.  This is permitted by the C++ langauge standard.

However, you apparently do not get the `operator+` overload(s) that take `std::string` (or, more correctly, `std::basic_string`) operands.  To get those you have to include `<string>`.

The compiler knows full well what `std::string` is, but when it attempts to find an `operator+` overload for the two `std::string` objects, it fails and reports all of the `operator+` overloads that it considered but rejected.

Comment: +1, thanks. The key point seems to be in your last paragraph.  That is, if it only finds templated versions of `operator+` then it produces all that it can't find conversions for, and it does this intentionally.  However, it seems that if there's a non-template overload of `operator+` then it only complains once.  I guess this is a feature after all.

Comment: Your answer saved me TONS of time.  One of the things that MS poorly documents (IMO) is precisely which includes to use for a given class or set of functions.  I was reusing code and did not know that I needed <string>...after all I already had <string.h>.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @ChronoFish:  `<string.h>` and `<string>` are two different headers:  the former is from the C Standard Library; the latter is from the C++ Standard Library.  Aside from their similar names, they are entirely unrelated.  Which headers include which other headers is largely unspecified.  It is up to the programmer to include the correct headers.  You can find out which header you need to include from one of many places--[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/), for example.  MSDN should also have this documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> that it doesn't just complain that no suitable operator exists.

That's IMO a plain stupid compiler behavior, if that's what happens. Surely it should first tell you what's wrong (i.e no suitable operator exists) and then list all the considered templates.

> one is that it gives this error for each overloaded + operator that involves templates. This tells me that the compiler has absolutely no way of ruling out that any of these + are not meaningful;

In general, it cannot do this, because for example `std::_Vector_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>` might be a base class of `std::basic_string<>`, which means that that one operator overload might be viable and deduction succeed. Argument deduction is the phase in compiling a C++ at that stage that figures these things out, and the compiler just reports the result of argument deduction to you.

Comment: VC10 does report that no suitable operator exists (`error C2676: binary '+' : 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`). It's reported at the end of the list of considered overloads, not before, but at least it's reported. (I don't know whether the OP's compiler, VC8, did this too; I don't have that installed anywhere to check.)

Comment: Indeed it does James:  `1>.\test.cpp(21) : error C2676: binary '+' : 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator`  I just didn't get quite that far since there were 37 errors.