# C2784 error when building exbin example for libmimetic (mimetic) library with VS2013 x64

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, stl, compiler-errors

When building **exbin** example for **libmimetic** library with VS2013 x64 I get several errors, which are the same as the first of them:

```
exbin.cxx:202: error: C2784: 'std::_Vb_iterator<_Alloc>
std::operator +(_Alloc::difference_type, std::_Vb_iterator<_Alloc>)' :
could not deduce template argument for 'std::_Vb_iterator<_Alloc>' from 'unsigned __int64'
```

The troubled function is the following:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void parse(Iterator bit, Iterator eit, string& fqn)
{
    string sep = "From ";
    Iterator it = utils::find_bm(bit, bit + sep.length(), sep);   //<<<<ERROR
    if(it == bit)
    {
        parseMboxFile(bit, eit, fqn);
    } else {
        g_messages++;
        MimeEntity me(bit, eit);
        parsePart(me, fqn);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

The library itself is compiled without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `std::_Vb_iterator` lead me to here: [With templates: Operator resolved first or conversion resolved first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822366/with-templates-operator-resolved-first-or-conversion-resolved-first)

where the problem was caused because of missing headers. Make sure your template function includes header `<string>` and in files where the function is called, make sure that the data structure's header (such as `vector`) are included.

Comment: The source includes <iostream>, <sstream>, <iterator>, <fstream>, <cassert>, <mimetic/mimetic.h>. The headers like <string> etc are included inside the mimetic.h. It seems like a valid **operator +** realization is missing...

Comment: The file which contains this function, should include `<string>` directly. Maybe that's not the cause of the problem, but it's good practice and will reduce chance of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error for the same code line (see above):

```
exbin.cxx:202: error: C2676: binary '+' : 'mimetic::StdFile::iterator'
does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable
to the predefined operator
```

There's a file **mimetic/os/file_iterator.h** in the mimetic's sources which declares:

```
struct ifile_iterator: public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, char>
{
    ifile_iterator();    
    ifile_iterator(StdFile* f);
    ifile_iterator(const ifile_iterator&);
    ifile_iterator& operator=(const ifile_iterator&);
    ~ifile_iterator();    
    inline ifile_iterator& operator++();
    inline ifile_iterator operator++(int);
    inline reference operator*();
    inline bool operator!=(const ifile_iterator& right) const;
    inline bool operator==(const ifile_iterator& right) const;
private:
    void cp(const ifile_iterator&);
    void setBufsz();
    enum { defBufsz = 4096 }; // default buffer size(4 missing getpagesize)
    void underflow();
    bool m_eof;
    value_type* m_buf;
    value_type* m_ptr;
    int m_count;
    StdFile* m_pFile;
    unsigned int m_read; //bytes read so far
    unsigned int m_bufsz;
};

inline
ifile_iterator ifile_iterator::operator++(int) // postfix
{
    ifile_iterator cp = *this;
    operator++();
    return cp;
}

//...
```

What's missing?